# How to close OpenGL Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a problem with my activity which showing CUBE 3D (simple OpenGL example). When I pressing back key on my phone or emulator, it should return to main menu, but instead of returning nothing happens. Any clue?

Here's the code:

```
public class Graphic3D extends Activity {
   private GLSurfaceView glView;  // Use subclass of GLSurfaceView (NEW)

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // Allocate a custom subclass of GLSurfaceView (NEW)
      glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
      setContentView(glView);  // Set View (NEW)
   }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // ????????
}


@Override
   protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      glView.onPause();

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      glView.onResume();
   }
}
```

MySurfaceView class:

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
   Graphics3DRenderer renderer;    // Custom GL Renderer

   // For touch event
   private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320.0f;
   private float previousX;
   private float previousY;

   // Constructor - Allocate and set the renderer
   public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      renderer = new Graphics3DRenderer(context);
      this.setRenderer(renderer);
      // Request focus, otherwise key/button won't react
      this.requestFocus();  
      this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   }

   // Handler for key event
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent evt) {
      switch(keyCode) {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:   // Decrease Y-rotational speed
            renderer.speedY -= 0.3f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:  // Increase Y-rotational speed
            renderer.speedY += 0.3f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:     // Decrease X-rotational speed
            renderer.speedX -= 0.3f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:   // Increase X-rotational speed 
            renderer.speedX += 0.3f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:// Zoom out (decrease z)
            renderer.z -= 0.4f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP: // Zoom in (increase z)
            renderer.z += 0.4f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
             renderer.speedY = 0;
             renderer.speedX = 0;
             renderer.z      = -6.0f;
             break;
      }
      return true;  // Event handled
   }

   // Handler for touch event
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent evt) {
      float currentX = evt.getX();
      float currentY = evt.getY();
      float deltaX, deltaY;
      switch (evt.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Modify rotational angles according to movement
            deltaX = currentX - previousX;
            deltaY = currentY - previousY;
            renderer.angleX += deltaY * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
            renderer.angleY += deltaX * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
      }
      // Save current x, y
      previousX = currentX;
      previousY = currentY;
      return true;  // Event handled
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an Activity, calling `finish()` will close the current Activity. If you haven't closed the main menu Activity, it should "open" itself.

If you need to start an Activity again, for example if your menu Activity is closed, you can do the following.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: should I put this to onBackPressed() method?

Comment: Yes, if that's the place where you want to take action (by pressing the back key).

Comment: There's a problem in something else that i don't mensioned. In class MySurfaceView (code added to main post) there's a override method onKeyDown (for 3d manipulation). When I pressing back key, debugger showing me calling this overrided method. Problem is that i can't paste code for onBackPressed() because MySurfaceView not implements Activity class...